# Python BeautifulSoup accounting for missing data on website when writing to csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am practicing my web scraping skills on the following website: "http://web.californiacraftbeer.com/Brewery-Member"

The code I have so far is below. I'm able to grab the fields that I want and write the information to CSV, but the information in each row does not match the actual company details. For example, Company A has the contact name for Company D and the phone number for Company E in the same row.

Since some data does not exist for certain companies, how can I account for this when writing rows that should be separated per company to CSV? What is the best way to make sure that I am grabbing the correct information for the correct companies when writing to CSV?

```
"""
Grabs brewery name, contact person, phone number, website address, and email address 
for each brewery listed.
"""    

import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

url = "http://web.californiacraftbeer.com/Brewery-Member"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
company_name = soup.find_all(itemprop="name")
contact_name = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_MAINCONTACT"})
phone_number = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_PHONE1"})
website = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "ListingResults_Level3_VISITSITE"})    

def scraper():
    """Grabs information and writes to CSV"""
    print("Running...")
    results = []
    count = 0
    for company, name, number, site in zip(company_name, contact_name, phone_number, website):
        print("Grabbing {0} ({1})...".format(company.text, count))
        count += 1
        newrow = []
        try:
            newrow.append(company.text)
            newrow.append(name.text)
            newrow.append(number.text)
            newrow.append(site.find('a')['href'])
        except Exception as e: 
            error_msg = "Error on {0}-{1}".format(number.text,e) 
            newrow.append(error_msg)
        results.append(newrow)
    print("Done")
    outFile = open("brewery.csv","w")
    out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='\n')
    out.writerows(results)
    outFile.close()

def main():
    """Runs web scraper"""
    scraper()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If some data does not exist for certain companies then store that data as null string(' ') so that it will skip that column while writing in csv.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `zip` to iterate through all those arrays simultaneously:

```
for company, name, number, site in zip(company_name, contact_name, phone_number, website):
```

Comment: Thanks, this takes care of the unpacking issue that I had!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I realized that since the company details for each company are contained in the Div class "ListingResults_All_CONTAINER ListingResults_Level3_CONTAINER", I could write a nested for-loop that iterates through each of these Divs and then grabs the information I want within the Div.